# Javascript option handling

Tags: javascript

What is a better/shorter way to write option handling in JavaScript. Instead of the following pattern?

```
    if(typeof p_options.default_imageset !== "undefined") {
        default_imageset = p_options.default_imageset;
    } else {
        default_imageset = 'mm';
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
var default_imageset = p_options.default_imageset || 'mm';
```

If `p_options.default_imageset` is truthy (not `0`, `null`, `false`, `''`, etc.), the operator short-circuits.

Although usually I do it the other way around:

```
var value = supplied_value || default_value;
```

Comment: Perfect how do you handle the same case, but `0` being a valid option value. In that case, if you provided `0` it would use the fallback.

Comment: @Justin: You'll have to use something like `var value = typeof supplied !== 'undefined' ? supplied : default;`